# JBoss bean validation needs to call an EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jpa-2.0, bean-validation

I am writing bean validation on my persistence model. I need to call my EJB Bean in order to retrieve some configuration parammeter from DB. How can I achieve this?

I tried to mark my EntityValidator as @Stateless and @LocalBean, but JBoss is still treats my EntityValidator as POJO. Can I do something about it? Alternatively, how can I retrieve EJB from POJO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Bean Validation 1.0, you can't get EJBs injected into validators out of the box. This will change with Bean Validation 1.1, though.

Currently you have the following possibilities:

- Retrieve the EJB via JNDI: `MyEjb myEjb = InitialContext.doLookup(myEjbName);`
- Implement a custom [ConstraintValidatorFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e2697) which injects EJB references into created validator objects
- Use [Seam Validation](http://www.seamframework.org/Seam3/ValidationModule), which enables dependency injection for validator objects using `@Inject` (disclaimer: I'm the author of Seam Validation)

With Bean 1.1 this will be possible [out of box](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/1.1.0.cr1/#d0e11289).

Comment: We are using CODI for doing the same with CDI beans. I guess the implementation is similar to Seam-Validation.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, injection is not working in validators.

I've [read](http://beanvalidation.org/proposals/BVAL-238/) that there are plans for future extension of bean validaton to enable exactly that behaviour.

However, there should be extension like seam or [deltaspike](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/deltaspike.html), which could enabled you to provide injection.

Check this:
[injection in validators](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/latest/reference/en-US/html/validation-dependency-injection.html#d0e11441)

Comment: CODI as well as Seam3 support it. Since both merge to DeltaSpike, I guess they will support the same. We prefer CODI and DeltaSpike because they are tested with a lot of environments and the footprint is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think jboss will inject your bean to the JPA validator.

You can use JDNI to lookup your EJB for POJO.